# How to do for inside for with some condition with java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
List<SoldProduct> soldProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product product : products) {
        for (ProductCartDTO productCartDTO : dto.getProducts()) {
            if(product.getId().equals(productCartDTO.getIdProduct())){
               soldProducts.add(new SoldProduct(product, productCartDTO.getSerialList()));
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried many times but can't get the same result with Java 8 Streams.

Is it possible to get this exact behaviour with Streams? If yes, please, give me an example.

Thanks

Comment: Are `products` and `dto.getProducts()` Lists? Can there be multiple `ProductCartDTO` instances that match the same `Product` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cartesian join of two lists, to find objects with matching product id, is very bad for performance.

Suggest you build a `Map<Integer, Product>`, of course assuming there can be only one product with a given id.

```
Map<Integer, Product> productById =
        products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getId, Function.identity()));

List<SoldProduct> soldProducts =
        dto.getProducts()
           .stream()
           .filter(d -> productById.containsKey(d.getIdProduct()))
           .map(d -> new SoldProduct(productById.get(d.getIdProduct()), d.getSerialList()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The code is not any prettier than the original code, and now that it has been optimized to use a `Map` for faster product lookup, you likely won't need parallel processing, so you might as well stick with the original code.

Or rather, fix the original code to use `Map` too:

```
Map<Integer, Product> productById = new HashMap<>();
for (Product product : products)
    productById.put(product.getId(), product);

List<SoldProduct> soldProducts = new ArrayList<>();
for (ProductCartDTO productCartDTO : dto.getProducts()) {
    Product product = productById.get(productCartDTO.getIdProduct());
    if (product != null) {
        soldProducts.add(new SoldProduct(product, productCartDTO.getSerialList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i decide to use your suggestion. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As @Andreas said, your nested loop approach is not very efficient, but here's how you can convert it to streams:

```
List<SoldProduct> soldProducts = products.stream()
    .flatMap(product -> dto.getProducts()
        .stream()
        .filter(productCartDTO -> product.getId().equals(productCartDTO.getIdProduct()))
        .map(ProductCartDTO::getSerialList)
        .map(serialList -> new SoldProduct(product, serialList)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```